# Unable to assign permission set for guest license user

Tags: apex, profile, permission-sets

I have create a test/demo org from environment hub, stuck in assigning permission to guest license user.

where as it's working perfectly in prod and test sandbox environment.

permission set was created with --None-- license type.

[image]

Comment: Read All and Edit All permissions are being phased out for Guest Users. I suspect this may be that your new org is Spring 21...?

Comment: yes it is,   now what is the work around?

Comment: Don't try to give view all to a guest user and make sure to use apex without sharing code to perform your processing without any sharing considerations.

Comment: Yes removing view all and modify all helps to resolve this issue but I need have edit record access to update the records. now facing *Invalid Object Access* error

Comment: You must move this logic into "without sharing" apex code in order to avoid such issues.

Answer (score 1):

As per the error message, View All permission is selected for DevOps Fields object in the OutboundPermission Permission Set. Guest User cannot have View All permission on DevOps Field object. So, you are getting this error.

Create a separate permission set without View All permission on the DevOps Field object. Before assigning it to the Guest User, make sure the Permission Set doesn't have View All or Modify All on any of the objects.

Guest User cannot have more than Read and Create permissions on the objects.